# Optimization problem with a constraint dependent on the absolute value of the argument

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I've run into an optimization problem that's giving me a bit of trouble.
Essentially, for some matrix $\mathbf{A}$, I want to find a sparse vector $\mathbf{x}$ that fulfills $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{0}$ as well as $|\mathbf{A}||\mathbf{x}|=\mathbf{b}$, for some known vector $\mathbf{b}$ (in this context, $|.|$ refers to an elementwise absolute value).

So far, I've come up with the idea of finding the solutions to $\mathbf{|A|x}=\mathbf{b}$, then restricting possible solutions to vectors with either all positive or negative entries. Given those vectors, I could construct a set of vectors whose elementwise absolute values fall in the determined space, then projecting it onto the kernel of $\mathbf{A}$. This feels wrong though, and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to go about it.

Edit: $\mathbf{A}$ is an underdetermined matrix

Comment: |A||x|=b is a nonconvex constraints, you can model the absolute value of $x$ with binary variables